# SQL запрос с одной таблицы в другую

Tags: sql, запрос

У меня есть таблица с двумя полями name,price. Есть вторая создана таблица с полем summ.Нужно запросом SQL суммировать все числа с поля price и записать их в другую таблицу в поле summ. Пример Дмитрий 20 Игорь 30 (1 таблица), суммируем 20+30 и записываем 50 в другую таблицу в столбец summa

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо уточнять задачу под ответом. Дополните вопрос кнпкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/985702/edit). Дайте пример входных данных и пример выхода запроса (текстом), как вы его себе представляете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобный запрос может выглядеть вот так (правда не тестировал):

```
insert into table2.summ value (SELECT SUM(price) FROM table1)
```

Comment: Эти числа нужно суммировать а потом записать их.

Comment: @Дмитрий исправил

Comment: Мой запрос такой insert into money.moneys values (SELECT SUM(cash) FROM cash) Где money - таблица 2, а   moneys - столбец куда записывать сумму, cash (первый) - таблица, cash (второй) столбец с числами. Ругается на SELECT. PostgreSQL и SQL отличаются сильно? Я работаю в PostgresSQL

Comment: Я раньше не работал с PostgreSQL, но думаю в Вашем случае SELECT лучше завернуть в ещё одни скобки, типа 
 `insert into table2.summ value ((SELECT SUM(price) FROM table1))`

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам хоть как то помог - проголосуйте за него или отметьте как правильный. Спасибо.

Comment: Появилась другая проблема :D [42P01] ОШИБКА: отношение "money.moneys" не существует. У меня money - таблица, moneys - столбец куда записывать сумму.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. С основным вопросом по селекту как я понял мы проблему решили.